# Convert excel to json but not having the expected format

Tags: python, json, excel, dataframe, object

I have this code in python that turns excel into json  but the output is not the format that I'm expected to:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('/home/bird/Downloads/file.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
outpath = r"home/bird/Downloads/data.json"    

plant_id= data.id
name = data.name
description = data.description
water=data.w
sun=data.s     
container = {}
x = 0

while x< len(plant_id):    
    container[plant_id[x]]= [
        {"plant_id: ":plant_id[x],
        "name: ": name[x],
        "description: ": description[x],
        "health:": {"water": water[x], "sun":sun[x]},
        },
    ]
    x=x+1     
df = pd.DataFrame(container)
df.to_json(outpath, indent=4)
```

I have the following output:

```
{
    "pl-01":{
        "0":{
            "plant_id: ":"pl-01",
            "name: ":"corn",
            "description: ":"yadayadayada",
            "health":{                
                "water":"30%",
                "sun":"5%"
            }
         }    
      },    
    ...
 }
```

What I want is slightly different :

```
{ 
    {
        "plant_id: ":"pl-01",
        "name: ":"corn",
        "description: ":"yadayadayada",
        "health":{ 
            "water":"30%",
            "sun":"5%",
        }
    },
...
}
```

I have colors in my excel cells (green/yellow...) for the exposure column, how do I insert that in my json file in order to get a new field -> `"color": "green"` (for example) please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

container = {}
for x in range(len(plant_id)):
    container[plant_id[x]] = {"plant_id: ":plant_id[x],
                              "name: ": name[x],
                              "description: ": description[x],
                              "health:": {"water": water[x], "sun":sun[x]},
                              "color": exposure[x]}

with open(outpath, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(container, outfile)
```

When creating each entry in the container you can add any field you like, here I added a field "color" with the value "green" or "red" depending on the value of exposure at index x.

Note that you have extra characters in the field names that are probably unnecessary: `"plant_id: "` should be `"plant_id"`, `"name: "` should be `"name"` etc.

If you want to not have a dictionary in your output (as per your example):

```
    with open(outpath, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(set(container.values()), outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. For the exposure column there are colors in each cell not number. So the condition is not valid, I guess with the hexadecimal notation that could work... I've try not using the container because it adds a new field but i don't know how to do...

Comment: What is wrong with adding to the container? You can remove the color field if you want later, but how can you get it in the json without it? I guess I don't understand what you want in the output. Please update the question with what output you want, including the exposure field

Comment: By previous comment was not clear sorry. First, can I use the container but not having these 2 fields in the output:  "pl-01":{ "0":{. In my first comment, I show what I'm expected for the output.

Comment: Secondly, in my exposure column, I have only colors in my excel file. I was wondering how can I translate this info in my json: for instance I have a green cell in my excel and I want to add a new field in my container like "color":"green" (if it's green obviously). Do I have to use the hexadecimal notation ?

Comment: the 2 fields is because you used a dataframe which I already removed. For the color, you'll have to extract the colors to anther variable (exposure) and then just put it as a field. I suggest you run the code from the answer and see if it gets closer to what you want before commenting. For the exposure I put in a sample code for you to change as you did not specify where this information is coming from

Comment: I still have one field :  "pl-01":{   instead of 2  fields :  "pl-01":{ "0":{ . How can I remove it please ?

Comment: For the exposure, I have in the excel file a colum called exposure that contains different colors (green , yellow, orange, red, purple, blue). I want to get the color of each cell from xlsx with python and put the result in my json file in a new field ( "color": "blue")

Comment: the output you show is not a dictionary of dictionaries, are you looking for a set? you can try to cast set(container.values) and save that to the json file. Does this look more like what you need?

Comment: For the colors, I would ask this in another question although I'm sure google will know how to extract cell colors using python

Comment: It's more a set of dictionaries what I want (see the third code in my first comment please). I've tried already to cast but I have : 'TypeError: builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable'.

Comment: @Smith you need () after .values, it won't work however if you have a nested dict like you have for "health", consider changing that into a tuple